# Running SonarQube analysis scan - SonarSource build-wrapper

Tags: c++, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm new to running SonarQube scans and I get this error message in the log in Jenkins:

> 16:17:39 16:17:36.926 ERROR - The only way to get an accurate analysis of your C/C++/Objective-C project is by using the SonarSource build-wrapper. If for any reason, the use of the build-wrapper is not possible on your project, you can bypass it with the help of the "sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output.bypass=true" property. By using that property, you'll switch to an "at best" mode that could result in false-positives and false-negatives.

Can someone please advise where I can find and run this SonarSource build-wrapper?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Contact support. The same people who gave you the plugin license should have also told you about the build wrapper.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To solve this issue, download the Build Wrapper directly from your SonarQube Server, so that its version perfectly matches your version of the plugin:

Build Wrapper for Linux can be downloaded from URL

```
http://localhost:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
```

Unzip the downloaded Build Wrapper,
Configure it in your PATH because it's just more convenient

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/where/you/unzip
```

Once done, Run below commands.

```
build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir <dir-name> <build-command>
build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir build_output make clean all
```

Once all this done, you have to modify your sonar-project.properties file with following line. Note the dir-name is same directory which we defined in previous command.

```
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=<dir-name>
```

and then you can run the sonar scanner command.

```
sonar-scanner
```

this will do the analysis against your code. For more details, you can check this [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7996665).

Comment: I get the following error (probably related to the lack of a valid signature) 

dyld: warning: could not load inserted library 'libinterceptor.dylib' into library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
 libinterceptor.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of 'libinterceptor.dylib'
 libinterceptor.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

Comment: @WernerAltewischer not faced this issue .. need to check about this.

Comment: export part saved my day. Actually, this wasn't mentioned properly in the sonarqube documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Contacted support, turns out this was caused by missing the argument sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output in the scanner begin command.

Answer (score 3):

Build wrapper downloads:

- Linux: https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
- macOS: https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-macosx-x86.zip
- Windows: https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-win-x86.zip

Some links covering how to run the build wrapper:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/
- https://blog.sonarsource.com/with-great-power-comes-great-configuration/

Comment: Unfortunatly the wrapper download is down. The download link gives the error:  "Repository path missing or not specified."

Comment: @HansvanderLaan Updated the download link.

Comment: i tried all links and none works

Comment: Updated download links again